# How can I make this Ruby on Rails page more efficient?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, performance

I'm building a site where users can track their collection of figures for Dungeons & Dragons (www.ddmdb.com).  The models/relationships involved in this funcitonality are the following:

**User:**

- id
- login (username)
- *a bunch of other fields*

**Miniature:**

- id
- name
- number (# in the set, not count)
- release_id (foreign key)
- *a bunch of other fields and foreign keys*

**Ownership:**

- id (is this really even needed?)
- user_id
- miniature_id
- have_count
- favorite (boolean)

The pertinent relationships I have set up are as follows:

**User:**

- has_many :ownerships
- has_many :miniatures, :through => :ownerships, :uniq => true, :conditions => "ownerships.have_count > 0"
- has_many :favorites, :through => :ownerships, :source => :miniature, :uniq => true, :conditions => "ownerships.favorite = true"

**Miniatures:**

- has_many :ownerships
- has_many :owners, :through => :ownerships, :source => :user, :uniq => true, :conditions => "ownerships.have_count > 0"

**Ownership:**

- belongs_to :user
- belongs_to :miniature

I have a page where user's can both view and update their collection, as well as view other user's collections.  It contains a list of all the miniatures on the site and a text box next to each where the user can enter how many of each miniature they have.  This functionality also exists in sub-lists of miniatures (filtered by type, release, size, rarity, etc.)

When a user creates an account they have no entries in the ownership.  When they use the collection page or sub-list of miniatures to update their collection, I create entries in the ownership table for only the miniatures on the submitting page.  So if it's the full Collection list I update all minis (even if the count is 0) or if it's a sub-list, I only update those miniatures.  So at any time a particular user I may have:
  - no entries in ownership
  - entries for some of the miniatures
  - entries for all the miniatures.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to query the database with a LEFT JOIN using a "Rails method" so that if a user doesn't have an entry for a miniature in Ownerships it defaults to a have_count of 0.  Currently I query for each user_id/miniature_id combination individually as I loop through all miniatures and it's obviously really inefficient.

**View:**

```
<% for miniature in @miniatures %>
  <td><%= link_to miniature.name, miniature %></td>
  <td><%= text_field_tag "counts[#{miniature.id}]", get_user_miniature_count(current_user, miniature), :size => 2 %></td>
<% end %>
```

**Helper:**

```
def get_user_miniature_count(user, miniature)
  ownerships = user.ownerships
  ownership = user.ownerships.find_by_miniature_id(miniature.id)
  if ownership.nil?
    return 0
  else
    return ownership.have_count
  end
end
```

An alternate solution would be creating entries for all miniatures when a user signs up, but then I would also have to add a 0 have_count for all users when a new miniature is added to the database after they sign up.  That seems like it could get a bit complex, but perhaps it's the right way to go?

Is there a way to do the join and supply a default value for miniatures where there's no entries in the Ownership table for that particular user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fd's suggestion and information found at http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/52385, I created the following method:

```
def miniature_count(miniature_id)
  if @counts.nil?
    @counts = Hash.new
    ownerships.collect{|o| @counts[o.miniature_id] = o.have_count }
  end
  count = @counts[miniature_id] || 0
end
```

This ends up being faster than the *detect* approach.

I picked *miniature_count* over *owns* for the name because *owns* sounds like a method that should return a boolean instead of an integer.

**Query Every Entry**

Completed in 2.61783 (0 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 1.14116 (43%) | DB: 1.34131 (51%) | 200 OK [http://ddmdb/collection/1]

**Detect Methods**

Completed in 2.20406 (0 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 1.87113 (84%) | DB: 0.21206 (9%) | 200 OK [http://ddmdb/collection/1]

**Hash Method**

Completed in 0.41957 (2 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.19290 (45%) | DB: 0.10735 (25%) | 200 OK [http://ddmdb/collection/1]

I will definitely need to add caching, but this is definitely an improvement.  I also suspect I am prematurely optimizing this code, but it's a small site and a 2.5 second load time was not making me happy.

Comment: Nice work, agree on the method name, I just picked something quickly.  Names are very important, so I'm glad you found something that is more expressive.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would say is that the User model should own the code that works out how many of a given miniature the user owns, since it seems like "business logic" rather than view formatting.

My suggestion would be to add a method to your User model:

```
def owns(miniature_id)
  o = ownerships.detect { |o| o.miniature_id == miniature_id }
  (o && o.have_count) || 0
end
```

Dry-coded, ymmv.

Edit:  Note that ownerships is cached by Rails once loaded and detect is not overridden by ActiveRecord like find is, and so acts as you would expect it to on an Array (ie no database operations).

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for, though the method name isn't very... obvious in my opinion.  I was expecting something like ownerships.includes or ownerships.contains.  I tried this in the console and it looks promising.  I will try it with my app next.  Thanks!

Comment: include? is indeed a method, but it is used for finding an exact matching object, you don't have the object you are trying to find, only the value of an attribute on that object (though this attribute happens to be unique within the scope you are searching).  find is actually a synonym for detect.

Comment: To clarify that last bit, find is a synonym for detect on Enumerable objects.  I understand that ActiveRecord overrides this behaviour for its objects/collections, but only on find and not detect.  http://www.rubycentral.com/book/ref_m_enumerable.html

Comment: This helped a bit but didn't have the boost I was hoping for - delay moved from DB to Rendering.  It's searching through ~1000 rows with each entry. Would a hash help?
Before: 2.61783 sec | Rendering: 1.14116 (43%) | DB: 1.34131 (51%)
After: 2.20406 sec | Rendering: 1.87113 (84%) | DB: 0.21206 (9%)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but the way you've specified the relationships seems sufficient for rails to figure out the counts on its own? Have you tried that?

edit:
Re the discussion in the comments...how about this:

```
<% ownerships=current_user.ownerships %> 
<% for miniature in @miniatures %>
  <td><%= link_to miniature.name, miniature %></td>
  <td><%= text_field_tag "counts[#{miniature.id}]", get_miniature_count(ownerships, miniature), :size => 2 %></td>
<% end %>
```

Where `get_miniature_count()` just iterates through the supplied ownerships and returns 0 or the count if the miniature appears in the list? I think this will avoid going back to the DB again in each iteration of the 'for'.

edit 2: I'd also suggest firing up script/console and trying to do what you want in ruby directly, i.e. test for the miniatures membership in the ownerships list thinking in terms of ruby not SQL. Often, rails and activerecord is smart enough to do the necessary SQL black magic for you behind the scenes, given it knows the relationships. If you find a user and then do user.methods you'll see what is available.

Comment: I could do user.ownerships but that would only list the entries that user has records for, not the ones he doesn't.

Comment: yes but can't you reuse it rather than computing it every time?

Comment: to clarify what I mean, can't you grab user.ownerships and then use that throughout the view (using ruby to determine if a miniature is in the ownerships, rather than doing a find on every iteration).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to go about doing that.  Hence the question :-)